# How to avoid extra blankline in a textview while using \n to separate two sentences?

Tags: android, textview

We have developed a handwriting app which will display the words we say in 3 lines and 4 lines in upper and lower cases.

We are separating the uppercase and lowercase with an 'end of line' (\n) but in some cases when an uppercase word is right on the far right side edge, there is  no room for the \n character to occupy so it will automatically occupy the nextline and result in an extra line in between the uppercase characters and lowercase characters.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can add the /n before the next text in place of at the end.

Comment: now the text is like this "uppercase"+\n+"lowercase" so it's already in front of lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by myself.It's possible to find the end and start point of a textview and that can be used for abstracting text in each line.
This is what I have done.May help someone.

```
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";
    String text = getText().toString();
    Layout layout = getLayout();
    int start = 0;
    int end;

    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        end = layout.getLineEnd(i);

        lines.add(text.substring(start, end));
        line = lines.get(i);
        start = end;
        String nwText = "";
        // if(line.startsWith(line.toUpperCase())){
        //
        // nwText = " "+ line+" ";
        // }
        // else{

        nwText = " " + line + " ";
        // }
        if(!nwText.equals(" \n "))
            newLines.add(nwText);
    }
    Paint mPaint = getPaint();
    int i = 0;
    // String[] textLines = Results.split("\\n+");
    // float textsize = getTextSize();

    for (String textLine : newLines) {
        // mPaint.setTextSize(textsize);
        int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);
        canvas.drawText(textLine, 0, baseline, mPaint);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the text fill the whole line (for example symbols are equal to a specific number) and if yes => no new line (\n), else => new line before lowercase